# Can't figure out how to set a condition in this PHP/ajax function

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm pretty novice with PHP and programming.

In my controller, I have this function (an ajax request) which gets data from a session and localstorage then inserts it into 2 tables.
I just want to put a condition to check before insertion if the lesson $session[0] is already in the table.

It's about booking a lesson, and as of now the function allows to book the same lesson over and over, which is not correct.

Here's the php code

```
    public function ajaxValidate() {

        if ($this->isUserConnected()) {

            //recupération des données envoyé par la requète ajax
            if(array_key_exists('lesson', $_GET)) {

                //leçon -> json -> php
                $lesson = json_decode($_GET['lesson']);
                $ID_user = $_SESSION['userConnected']["id"];

                foreach ($lesson as $session) {
                    $ID_booking = $this->bookings->insertBooking($ID_user);
                    $test = $this->bookings->insertBookingDetails($ID_booking, $session[0]);
                }

                echo $test;
            }
        } else {
            header('location:index.php?action=connexion');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

and here's the JS :

```
function onClickConfirmLessons() {
    //On récupère les données du localStorage
    onLoadLocalStorage();
    if (lesson.length == 0) {
        let tbody = document.getElementById('lesson');
        tbody.innerHTML = "";
        let row1 = document.createElement('tr');
        let cell1 = document.createElement('td');
        cell1.colSpan = 3;
        cell1.innerHTML = "<p>Vous n'avez aucun cours à confirmer</p>";
        row1.appendChild(cell1);
        tbody.appendChild(row1);
    } else {
        // js -> json
        lesson = JSON.stringify(lesson);
        //console.log(lesson);
        $.get('index.php?action=ajaxValidate', "lesson="+lesson, clearStorage);
    }
}

function clearStorage(test) {
    //console.log(test);
    lesson = JSON.parse(lesson);
    
    if (test) {
        let date = new Date();
        let msg = "Votre participation à bien été enregistrée le "+date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();

        window.localStorage.clear();

        display();
        let msgConfirm = document.getElementById("msgConfirm");
        msgConfirm.textContent = msg;

        let btnConfirmLessons = document.getElementById("confirmLessons");

        //On vérifie si le bouton de confirmation existe avant de le supprimer
        if (btnConfirmLessons) {
            //On récupère le parent du bouton de confirmation
            let parent = btnConfirmLessons.parentNode;

            //On supprime le bouton de confirmation
            parent.removeChild(btnConfirmLessons);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set a method in the model which gets the ID_lesson and return true or false :

```
    public function getOneLessonByID(string $ID_lesson): ?array
    {
        $query = $this -> connexion -> prepare("
                                                SELECT
                                                    `ID_booking`,
                                                    `ID_lesson`
                                                FROM
                                                    `bookings_details`
                                                WHERE 
                                                    ID_lesson = :ID_lesson
                                                ");
        $query -> bindValue(":ID_lesson",$ID_lesson);
        $query -> execute();
        $ID_Lesson = $query -> fetch();
        
        if($ID_Lesson == false)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return $ID_Lesson;
    }
```

and add it to the controller with a condition :

```
    public function ajaxValidate() {

        if ($this->isUserConnected()) {

            //recupération des données envoyé par la requète ajax
            if(array_key_exists('lesson', $_GET)) {

                //leçon -> json -> php
                $lesson = json_decode($_GET['lesson']);
                $ID_user = $_SESSION['userConnected']["id"];

                foreach ($lesson as $session) {

                    //test if exists in database
                    $ID_lesson = $this->bookings->getOneLessonByID($session[0]);

                    if (!$ID_lesson) {
                        $ID_booking = $this->bookings->insertBooking($ID_user);
                        $test = $this->bookings->insertBookingDetails($ID_booking, $session[0]);
                    } else {
                        $message = "Une erreur Serveur est survenue";
                        $class = "error";
                    }
                }
                echo $test;
            }
        } else {
            header('location:index.php?action=connexion');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work at all...

Comment: could you provide the JSON string that is being sent to the server?

Comment: also, please could you show what insertBooking() and insertBookingDetails() are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked it out !

here are the models :

```
public function insertBooking(int $ID_user): ?int {

    $query = $this->connexion->prepare('
                                        INSERT INTO `bookings`(
                                            `ID_user`,
                                            `date`
                                        )
                                        VALUES(
                                            :ID_user,
                                            NOW()
                                        )
                                    ');

    // Attribution de la valeur de l'ID de l'utilisateur à la variable liée :ID_user
    $query->bindValue(":ID_user", $ID_user);

    $test = $query->execute();

    // Vérification du succès de l'opération et retour de l'ID de la réservation insérée ou null en cas d'échec
    if($test) {
        return $this->connexion->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public function insertBookingDetails(int $ID_booking, int $ID_lesson): bool {

    $query = $this->connexion->prepare('
                                        INSERT INTO `bookings_details`(
                                            `ID_booking`,
                                            `ID_lesson`
                                        )
                                        VALUES(
                                            :ID_booking,
                                            :ID_lesson
                                        )
                                    ');

    // Attribution des valeurs des IDs de réservation et de cours aux variables liées :ID_booking et :ID_lesson
    $query->bindValue("ID_booking", $ID_booking);
    $query->bindValue("ID_lesson", $ID_lesson);

    // Exécution de la requête et retour du résultat de l'opération (true si réussie, sinon false)
    $test = $query->execute();

    return $test;
}

    public function checkExistingBooking(int $ID_user, int $ID_lesson): bool {

    $query = $this->connexion->prepare("
                                        SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                                        FROM
                                            `bookings_details`
                                        WHERE
                                            `ID_booking` IN (
                                                SELECT
                                                    `ID_bookings`
                                                FROM
                                                    `bookings`
                                                WHERE
                                                    `ID_user` = :ID_user
                                            )
                                        AND
                                            `ID_lesson` = :ID_lesson
                                    ");

    $query->bindValue(":ID_user", $ID_user);
    $query->bindValue(":ID_lesson", $ID_lesson);
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetch();

    // La fonction retourne true si le champ 'count' dans le résultat est 
    supérieur à zéro, indiquant qu'il existe des enregistrements correspondants.
    // Sinon, elle retourne false, ce qui signifie qu'il n'y a pas 
    d'enregistrements correspondants.
    return $result['count'] > 0;
}
```

here is the controller function :

```
    public function ajaxValidate() {
    // Vérification si l'utilisateur est connecté.
    if ($this->isUserConnected()) {

        // Vérification si la clé 'lesson' existe dans le tableau $_GET.
        if (array_key_exists('lesson', $_GET)) {

            // Récupération et décodage du JSON contenu dans la clé 'lesson' de $_GET.
            $lesson = json_decode($_GET['lesson']);
            // Récupération de l'ID de l'utilisateur connecté depuis la session.
            $ID_user = $_SESSION['userConnected']["id"];

            foreach ($lesson as $session) {

                // Vérifier si l'ID de la leçon n'existe pas déjà pour cet utilisateur dans la table `booking_details`.
                $existingBooking = $this->bookings->checkExistingBooking($ID_user, $session[0]);

                if (!$existingBooking) {
                    // Insertion d'une réservation dans la base de données pour l'ID utilisateur courant.
                    $ID_booking = $this->bookings->insertBooking($ID_user);

                    // Insertion des détails de la réservation pour l'ID_booking courant.
                    $test = $this->bookings->insertBookingDetails($ID_booking, $session[0]);
                } else {
                    // Si l'ID existe on renvoie null
                    $test = null;
                }
            }
            // Affichage de la valeur de la variable $test.
            echo $test;
        }
    } else {
        // Redirection vers la page de connexion si l'utilisateur n'est pas connecté.
        header('location:index.php?action=connexion');
        // Arrêt de l'exécution du script.
        exit();
    }
}
```

and voilà :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).